# How do I get the console to print out the strings that are in the GetSet class?

Tags: c#, class, http

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
string URL = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/";
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word: "); 
string Input = Console.ReadLine(); 
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(URL + Input);
List<GetSet> gs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetSet>>(response);

Console.ReadKey();    

  

public class GetSet 
{
   public string word {get; set;}
   public string origin {get; set;}
    
   public string definition {get; set;}
   public string partOfSpeech {get; set;}

}
```

I don't want to print out everything in the URL, only the strings that are present in GetSet class. I can't figure it out for the life of me. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: what are you having trouble with?  You probably want to start with a `foreach` loop and `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: If you [override `ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) then you can simply do: `foreach(var entry in gs){ Console.WriteLine(entry); }`

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `Console.WriteLine` along with the string you want to print. Since you're using a list, you have to seperately handle each object in that list.
Consider this piece of code.

```
foreach(var getset in gs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Word: {getset.word}");
}
```

We iterate through the collection of GetSet objects that you created using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetSet>>(response);` and use string interpolation (the `$""` syntax) to create a string. We then pass that string to WriteLine, which outputs that string as a line of text in the console.

Some varations on the above, illustrating some different ways of creating and passing strings:

`Console.WriteLine("someString");`

`Console.WriteLine(someVariable + "someString");`

`Console.WriteLine($"{someVariable} someString")`

Comment: Right, strings now do show up in the console, but they're empty. 
For example, it only outputs ```Definition:    ```.  
Here's the API that I'm using https://dictionaryapi.dev/
and here's how I wrote foreach loop
```foreach (var GetSet in gs)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Word: {GetSet.word}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Example: {GetSet.example}");
}```

Comment: I'd advise against naming the variable `GetSet` instead of `getset` or some other name, as it is exactly like the actual class name (and therefore the type) and creates ambiguity. Try using a truly distinct name for the loop variable. Anyhow; what you did should've worked. You should debug and check why those strings are empty; your problem is no longer about printing stuff to the console. So, go ahead and post a new question if you need more help! :-)

Comment: Noted, thanks a lot for your help and I appreciate your answers